# Separating text inside a <pre> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I wanted to try some basic web-scraping but ran into a problem since I am used to simple td-tags, in this case I had a webpage which had the following pre-tag and all the text inside of it which means it is a bit trickier to scrape it.

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
11111111
11111112
11111113
11111114
11111115
</pre>
```

Any suggestions on how to scrape each row?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If that is **exactly** what you want to parse, you can use the [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) function easily to get a list of rows, or you can tweak the [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = """
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
11111111 
11111112 
11111113
11111114
11111115 
</pre>""" # This is your content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
stuff = soup.find('pre').text
lines = stuff.split("\n") # or replace this by stuff.splitlines()
# print(lines) gives ["11111111", "11111112", "11111113", "11111114", "11111115"]
for line in lines:
    print(line)
# prints each row separately.
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if there are 5000 rows? To have the HTML content in the code would not be a solid solution. Here is an example, the exit address: https://check.torproject.org/exit-addresses

Comment: As for the example you gave, there is no HTML content, it just plaintext. Their bs4 would be useless there. So in that case you'd search for a specific sequence of repeated string(s) and use `split()` accordingly. In your case, the word `ExitNode` is repeated uniquely, so you'd do `s.split('ExitNode')`.

Answer (score 0):

If each line is indeed on a line by itself, why not just split the content into a list?

```
data = soup.find('pre').text
lines = data.splitlines()
```

You can pass `True` into the [splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=splitlines#str.splitlines) routine to keep the line endings if that's what you desire.